# How to get text from tag abbr using scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I've been trying to get text from abbr tag using scrapy, but it returns nothing.
I'd like to know why most people usually use xpath selector insead of css.

```
    <div class="display-post-action">






                            <div class="display-post-vote"> <span class="like-score ">0</span> <a title="กดปุ่มนี้เพื่อบอกว่าเนื้อหานี้ดี (กดอีกทีเพื่อยกเลิก)" class="icon-heart-like " href="javascript:void(0);"><span></span></a>
                                                                </div>
                            <div class="display-post-emotion"> <a class="emotion-vote" href="javascript:void(0);"> <span class="icon icon-emotion"></span> <span class="emotion-score ">0</span> </a> </div>
                            <div class="display-post-avatar">
                                                                    <a href="https://pantip.com/profile/5523231" target="_blank"> <img src="https://ptcdn.info/images/avatar_member_default.png"> </a>
                                <div class="display-post-avatar-inner"> <a class="display-post-name owner" id="5523231" target="_blank" href="https://pantip.com/profile/5523231">สมาชิกหมายเลข 5523231</a>



                                    <br><!--div no. 184.22.107.146 / 184.22.107.146-->
                                    <span class="display-post-timestamp" style="display:block"> <abbr title="11 ตุลาคม 2562 เวลา  11:52:39 น." data-utime="10/11/2019 11:52:39" class="timeago">11 ตุลาคม เวลา 11:52 น.</abbr>
                                                                                <span class="display-post-ip unfocus-txt">&nbsp;[IP: 184.82.25.133]</span>
                                                                        </span> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

```py
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://pantip.com/topic/39308092',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.container-inner'):
            yield {
                'Main post' : quote.css('div.display-post-wrapper.main-post.type div.display-post-story::text').getall(),
                'Owner' : quote.css('a.display-post-name.owner::text').getall(),
                'Time' : quote.css('span.display-post-timestamp abbr.timeago::text').getall(),
            }
```

Comment: This line --->'Time' : quote.css('span.display-post-timestamp abbr.timeago::text').getall(),

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve